# Why is LED lid when pin is set low?

Tags: programming, led

I made this simple piece of code, to make my LED flash.. Which it does when the pin is set low.. But how does that makes sense?

```
#include "pins_arduino.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED,LOW);
}
```

I am using the Wemos d1 - http://www.wemos.cc/

Comment: That depends entirely on how the LED is wired up. How have you wired your LED?

Comment: I am using a wemos d1

Comment: What's a wemos d1?

Comment: I am using this one http://www.wemos.cc/Products/d1_mini.html

Comment: I see no LED on the schematic. Do you mean the one built in to the ESP-12F module?

Comment: yes i am using the builtin led

Comment: If you can find a schematic of the internals of that proprietary module then you are a better man than me. But I will take an educated guess.

Comment: http://www.wemos.cc/Products/images/d1_mini.pdf 

Schmatic

Comment: I said module. Not development board. The ESP-12F module. The silver can sub-circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the LED is ON when LOW and OFF when HIGH then chances are the LED is connected between +3.3V and the IO pin with a suitable resistor.

When HIGH the IO pin is at +3.3V, so the voltage across the LED is 0V (3.3 - 3.3 = 0) and it is turned off.  When LOW the IO pin is at (nearly) 0V and the voltage across the LED (and its resistor) is 3.3V (3.3 - 0 = 3.3), so it lights up.